# How to change the value of a variable at run time from another script at remote machine?

Tags: python, serialization, rabbitmq, zeromq, simplexmlrpcserver

I have a local computer A and remote computer B. Computer A has script client.py Computer B has server.py Script client.py has a variable port. Let's say port = 5535.

I am running client.py on Computer A, which is using the port number for socket communication. I need to change the port number to another port number while the client.py is running so it will switch to another server at runtime after notifying the client to change the port number. I am using pyzmq to send data from the client to the server sending a continuous stream of data.

Is this scenario possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You may design / modify the (so far unseen) code so as to `PUSH` any such need to change a `port#` on-the-fly to the `PULL`-side, to release the `5535` and use another one.

The `PULL`-side shall then call `.disconnect()` and `.close()` methods, so as to release the said port `5535` ( plus notify that it has done so, perhaps by another `PUSH/PULL` to the `.bind()`-locked party, that it can now unbind and close the `.bind()`-locked port# `5535` too) and next setup a new connection to an announced "*`new_port#`*", received from the initial notification ( which ought have been already `.bind()`-locked on the `PUSH`-side, ought it not? :o) ).

That easy.